# Cufon (apparently) randomly working in IE7

Tags: cufon, internet-explorer-7

This is very strange. I'm the main developer of [www.inspirastudios.com.mx](http://www.inspirastudios.com.mx). I use cufon font replacement for the main navigation menu. I develop in Linux, so I use Internet Explorer in wine to test my site. The problem I'm getting is that cufon substitution is not working in my IE7 version. It works OK for other IE>7 versions and in any modern standard compliant browser. The strange thing is that, using some online testing sites, like http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ and http://browsershots.org the site looks OK, while in some others (like http://www.thumbalizr.com) it doesn't. What the hell is going on?

Comment: Why don't you use the `@font-face` CSS deceleration? It works with almost all of the modern browser and (surprise), kind-of with IE! Here's something to read: http://jontangerine.com/log/2008/10/font-face-in-ie-making-web-fonts-work#tutorial

Comment: Aren't there problems with these fonts looking crispy/aliased in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with online testing sites is that you don't know how they're set up.  I'm betting that some of those sites use IE7 straight, while others might be using IE8/9 with the render mode forced to IE7, or some other similar chicanery.  Never trust those sites if you actually care about your results.

Now, on to the results of your personal testing.  In IE-over-Wine, I've had a lot of weird stuff happen and I'm not convinced that it's truly comparable to actual Internet Explorer.  This goes double if you're using IES4Linux or similar, because you (again) really have no idea what's been done to it to make it run.  Always use a virtual machine (or actual Windows machine) if you possibly can.

I can confirm, though, that cufon appears to be functioning properly in IE7 as far as my copy of IE7 is concerned.  :)

Comment: Have you seen my site in your copy of IE7 and cufon worked there?

Comment: "*I can confirm, though, that cufon appears to be functioning properly in IE7 as far as my copy of IE7 is concerned.*"

Answer (score 1):

I am using HTML 5.
I have included following line to cufon code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.replace('.mid_body h1');</script>
```

the `<h1>`tag doesn't get cufon font 
but when I convert it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.replace('h1');</script>
```

it works!